# Social network comments and posts model in PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: postgresql, json, recursive, hierarchy

I'm trying to figure out a data structure for migrating from MongoDB to PostgreSQL. Within my `posts` table in Postgres, I have a `JSONB[]` array holding comments for the post.

The thing is that each element in the array only holds an `id` of the comment author, not the actual user info of the author. What would be the best way to perform a join on every element of that array to replace the author `id` for their data, or if not what would be a better way to do this?

For example, one of my post table rows might look like:

```
id: 5
author: 1
body: "Hello word"
comments: [{author:0, body: "It's me"}]
```

Where the comments column is a `JSONB` array.

My users table might look like:

```
id: 0
username: Dux
```

I do need threaded comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First the author table, that's easy.

```
CREATE TABLE author (
    authorid   serial  PRIMARY KEY,
    username   text    UNIQUE
);
```

Now we use a self-referential post table to create the hierarchical structure.

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id           serial  PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_post  int     REFERENCES posts,
    authorid     int     NOT NULL REFERENCES author,
    body         text    NOT NULL
);
```

Test data...

```
INSERT INTO author (authorid,username) VALUES
  (0, 'ecarroll'),
  (1, 'jbob');
INSERT INTO posts (id,parent_post,authorid,body) VALUES
  (0, null, 0, 'HALLO WORLD'),
  (1 ,0,    1, 'HALLO EVAN' );
```

Recursive query to get it working.

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(chain,author_un,text,id) AS (
   SELECT ARRAY[id], username, body, id
   FROM posts
   INNER JOIN author USING (authorid)
   WHERE parent_post IS NULL
   UNION ALL
     SELECT t.chain||p.id, username, p.body, p.id
     FROM t
     INNER JOIN posts AS p
       ON (t.id = p.parent_post)
     INNER JOIN author AS a
       USING (authorid)
)
SELECT *
FROM t;

 chain | author_un |    text     | id 
-------+-----------+-------------+----
 {0}   | ecarroll  | HALLO WORLD |  0
 {0,1} | jbob      | HALLO EVAN  |  1
(2 rows)
```

---

*For more information on this method, see my post here*

- [How to build a table for a private messaging system that supports replies?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167579/2639)