# Multiple tables perfomance hit (mysql)

Tags: mysql, performance

I've been thinking of introducing multiple tables each of which will store the chat history between two users in an attempt to not have a big table that would eventually be slow and hard to maintain.

Is there any limitation in having 1000s of seperate tables and if not, since each table is seperate doesn't that mean that queries on individual tables are unaffected by the existence of others?

Comment: In general it is a bad idea, what makes you suspect that a traditional database design would lead you into trouble?

Comment: chat history has been done very often. Search a bit more how other people have done it and what improvements have been suggested. I don't ever remember 1000s of separate tables. Don't do this. Don't prematurely optimize. Database are designed to handle big data. Trust them to do this well, and index properly.

Comment: See if this helps [How to create a flexible table schema for storing messages from different chats?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192172/how-to-create-a-flexible-table-schema-for-storing-messages-from-different-chats)

Comment: @Lennart , but why is it a bad Idea is what I'm interested in

Comment: @danblack after 100s of millions of rows there are issues. i know a relational db isn't best for data like this but I'm not trying to find a solution to a production problem, I'm trying to understand why my approach might be problematic in technical terms

Comment: Difficult to maintain

Comment: @lennart would it cause a performance hit though?

Comment: It will still share resources like cpu, memory, disk. Queries cant be reused, Low probability that read rows will be found in memory, etc

Comment: Databases engines are designed to handle huge numbers of rows, not huge numbers of columns, nor huge numbers of tables or databases.

Comment: @Rick James i understand but I'm encountering a lot of iodine complaining about performance after author 200 mil rows so i was trying to solve the problem by seperating things that don't really need to be together.