# What's the best way to represent an event from a system in a chat?

Tags: database-design, schema, hierarchy

```
Conversations
--------------
id


Messages
--------------
id
conversation_id
user_id
reply_to_id
content
created_at
```

I was looking at this question and I had a question: [How to build a table for a private messaging system that supports replies?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97963/how-to-build-a-table-for-a-private-messaging-system-that-supports-replies/167579#167579)

Let's say you have a chat and two users messaging each other back and forth, and then another person joins, so an event says `Third User has joined the chat`.

How would you represent the event in a schema? It's technically just another message without a user_id, but allowing user_id to be null seems to violate data integrity. Is it better to just create a separate table? How would you design that table to allow easy joining so that each even is in the proper time?

Comment: I got two ideas. Either have a junction table for the participants of a conversation with a timestamp when a user joined or left, or maybe see joining or leaving a special type of message and integrate it in the messages table.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like user_id being NULL create a new one, call it "system_event" and use it for these messages.

Comment: This is my preferred approach too.

Answer (score 0):

MUC and Pubsub provide end-users to create N number of chat groups and channels where the group restriction is not a complex one.

It has some default function to send an acknowledgment to the server. Just retrieve the function & reply to the conversation_id