# Recursive query on a self-referential table where each node has one link to its child's node

Tags: mysql, query, recursive, mysq-8.0

Consider the following table and data (fiddle available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eee6efd587aa6462ad0875ce1173d676)):

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  next_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (id,   next_id) VALUES
(1, 3),
(2, 3),
(3, 6),
(4, 5),
(5, 6),
(6, 8),
(7, 10),
(8, 9);
```

I want to be able to select only the rows starting from ID = 1 following the Next ID in a recursive way. That is, I want to select in this example the following rows:

| ID | Next ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 6 | 8 |
| 8 | 9 |

I realize it would be relatively easy with a programming language to achieve, but I'd like to know if anyone has an idea how to achieve that using pure SQL.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: [recursive CTE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=ccc349d53390e4185fd7623da4a29f27) - see [this instructions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/).

Comment: [MySQL manual on recursive CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive)

Comment: I managed to solve it using recursive CTE. Works greats.

Comment: I actually answered this here at home - could you put up your answer and mark it as correct so that the question isn't left hanging - it's of little use to anyone without an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the following (all the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c7adb5ab0d2d7b56462ed47c0487d15)):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id_, next_id_) AS
(
  SELECT id, next_id FROM test WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM test)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    c.next_id_, t.next_id
  FROM
    cte c
  JOIN test t
  ON c.next_id_ = t.id
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

Result:

```
rn  id_   next_id_
 1    1          3
 2    3          6
 3    6          8
 4    8          9
```

These queries are **tricky** and it can take one (well, me anyway) a while to get one's head around them, so I'll go through this line by line - as much for me as for you! :-) (or anybody else who's struggling with these delicate and (potentially **very**) complex beasts!).

So, first line

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id_, next_id_) AS
```

The `RECURSIVE` keyword is obligatory for MySQL, [MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=9aa726ee6014f4b10f167ce98598988c) & [PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=545ec6fbbca6fa49b2011082cd0977db) and throws an error for [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=0ff5e275eceddd1b9645cc754d0c136a), [SQLite](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0b5a4336dec3f7122a52433ef922becd) and [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=709de27995c70edc3a71f71914ddb313). You may or may not require the field definitions in the brackets - check it out yourself - most seem to accept it and it's a help when you're actually formulating your query!

Then:

```
SELECT id, next_id FROM test WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM test)
```

Our "seed" or "anchor" query - the first values in our `RECURSIVE CTE` - in this case, it's the tuple `(1, 3)`.

The obligatory `UNION ALL` is followed by the core of the recursive part of the query:

```
SELECT 
  c.next_id_, t.next_id
FROM
  cte c
JOIN test t
ON c.next_id_ = t.id
```

So, starting with `(1,3)`, we `SELECT` 3 (`c.next_id`) from the `RCTE` and a value from `test` by `JOIN`ing them `ON 3 = t.id` - now `t.id` is test's `PK` and therefore `UNIQUE`, so we obtain the tuple `(3, 6)`.

In the next iteration, we have `6` as our `cte.id_` and the `JOIN` picks up the `cte.next_id_` value of `8` in the `JOIN` - and so on to the end of the table - `8` then picks up `9` and the query terminates. Voilà - the desired result!

@RickJames kindly pointed out that there is a limit to the available depth of recursion. In MySQL, this is determined by the system variable `cte_max_recursion_depth`, which by default is equal to 1000 (see bottom of [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c7adb5ab0d2d7b56462ed47c0487d15)).

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'cte_max_recursion_depth';
```

Result:

```
Variable_name            Value
cte_max_recursion_depth   1000
```

It can be set on a session or a global basis.

```
SET cte_max_recursion_depth = 1200;    ✓
```

Rerun our `SHOW VARIABLES` command:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'cte_max_recursion_depth';
```

Result:

```
         Variable_name   Value
cte_max_recursion_depth   1200
```

Of course, it cannot be increased *ad infinitum* (or even to its Maximum Value of 4294967295) - systems only have finite resources - YMMV!

Comment: Yep that's what I did

Comment: Caution:  There is a limit to the depth of recursion that is supported.

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW - I wonder if there is a way to do it without "recursing".  PS - I am vaccinated and cannot understand why others are refusing.

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW - The death rate here (US) is much higher than in Ireland, but the case rate is much lower.  You seem to be in a "wave" that might be subsiding.  (I have been watching Johns Hopkins numbers.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131016/discussion-between-verace-get-vaccinated-now-and-rick-james).

Answer (score 3):

## Invert your tree representation

As an aside, here you're storing the linkage between a parent node and a child node **on the parent.** This is almost always bad. I can't think of any case where this would be desirable. How do you even create a parent with a link to a child, if you haven't yet created the child yet? You'll generally want to link on the child node the parent's ID,

Look what [Vérace - get VACCINATED NOW](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/301922/2639) has in his query and it requires a sub-query to find the root nodes.

```
WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM test)
```

This is bad for an obvious reason, **it assumes your whole table has only one root node.** If you go the other way, you can support trees, and multiple root nodes.

Consider this instead,

```
INSERT INTO test (id, parent_id) VALUES
(1, NULL),
(3, 1)
(6, 3)
(8, 6)
(9, 8)
```

This would simplify everything, be faster, and provide more functionality. The above

```
WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM test)
```

Can be rewritten as,

```
WHERE parent_id = NULL
```

For a very similar method of querying you can see an [example of this here, *"How to build a table for a private messaging system that supports replies?: Hierarchic Self-Referential Data"*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167579/2639).

Comment: Very nice answer - I'll try and include this in any future answsers of my own. Yours is the superior answer to this question - I "gave a man a fish" - you "taught the man to fish" - kudos!